# Render Inner Component in a Custom DOM Node in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, frontend, reactjs

Consider the following Component hierarchy:

```
var FundComponent = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
      return (
        <div>
        <UserComponent profile={data} />
        </div>
        );
    }
  });

var UserComponent = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
      return (
        <div>
        Some Stuff goes here
        </div>
        );
    }
  });

React.renderComponent(<FundComponent />, document.getElementById('fund'));
```

This will render `UserComponent` inside the `#fund` node in my HTML.

How can I render `UserComponent` in a specific node inside the `fund` node in my HTML ? eg:

```
<div id="fund">
<div id="otherStuff">Stuff</div>
<div id="user">**load UserComponentHere**</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading around a bit, I found out how to go about this. Feel free to correct me.

`React` has a different concept as to how to go about this.

Rather than pre-defining the html in the html file, we define it in the `render` function, like so:

```
var FundComponent = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="myOtherStuff1">
            <OtherComponent1 data={data} />  //other stuff
          </div>
          <div className="user">  //user
            <UserComponent profile={profile} />
          </div>
          <div className="myOtherStuff2">
            //can have component or other static stuff. Upto developer.
          </div>
          ...
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

React.renderComponent(<FundComponent />, document.getElementById('fund'));
```

And the html will be:
`<div id="fund"></div>`

And then, we can define `UserComponent` and `OtherComponent(s)` as we go.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding you, but you should simply be able to do:

```
React.renderComponent(<FundComponent />, document.getElementById('user'));
```

to render into the `#user` div.

Comment: What if `Fund` component holds other components too ? And each needs to be in a different node within `Fund` component ?